# Eclipse is not able to create pom.xml file in maven project, and the error is shown as "Failed to create the part's controls"

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly7AL.png)]

I have updated the eclipse, jdk and sts plugin. I want to create the pom.xml at the time of creation of maven projects.

How to solve this?

Comment: What eclpse version do you have and what plugins in which versions have you installed?

Comment: Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)

Comment: Posting images with stack traces is discouraged. copy the stack trace to the question as text in a code block.